# mac app running both java 8 & 9

Tags: java, macos, desktop-application, java-9

I am planning a migration from Java 8 to 9 and have many applications that are based on MRJAdapter and com.apple.eawt is not available with Java 9. I still need to maintain these applications with Java 8 for the near term and cannot disrupt my development environment.

Has anyone updated MRJAdapter, if not how have others approached this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The classes in `com.apple.eawt` are not accessible at compile-time in JDK 9 (at least not without using the `--add-exports` option to export the package). They are accessible at run-time so existing code that was compiled with older JDK releases and uses this Apple-specific API should continue to work with JDK 9. It's impossible to say if this will continue, as the `com.apple.eawt` has not been supported since JDK 6.

I don't know anything about MRJAdapter but the maintainers of that library should be made aware of [JEP 272: Platform-Specific Desktop Features](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272). That is the JEP that introduced supported replacements for the APIs in `com.apple.eawt`.